# VS Code ESLint No Quick Fixes Available on Svelte files only

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, svelte, prettier

For some reason, when I hover over an ESLint issue on a Svelte file, it'll state that it knows there's an issue, but that there's `no quick fixes available`.

[image]

However, if I go to a TypeScript file, I can easily click on `Quick Fix`.

[image]

Weirdly enough, it actually used to work for me, and then all of sudden it stopped working one day. I even tried to completely erase VS Code and start from scratch, but to no avail.

Here are the `devDependencies` in the **package.json** for linters I'm using:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.50.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
  "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.15.0",
  "prettier": "^2.8.3",
  "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.8.1",
}
```

*I'm using `eslint-plugin-svelte`, rather than `eslint-plugin-svelte3` (the official Svelte one), since [`eslint-plugin-prettier` recommends to use the non-official one](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#svelte-support)*.

Here's the pertinent info on the `.eslint.cjs` file:

```js
extends: [
  'eslint:recommended',
  'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  'plugin:svelte/recommended',
  'plugin:prettier/recommended',
],
plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
ignorePatterns: ['*.cjs', '*.config.js'],
parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
parserOptions: {
  extraFileExtensions: ['.svelte'],
  project: './tsconfig.json',
},
overrides: [
  {
    files: ['*.svelte'],
    parser: 'svelte-eslint-parser',
    // Parse the script tag in Svelte as TypeScript
    parserOptions: {
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      project: './tsconfig.json',
    },
  },
],
```

Here are my user settings on VS Code:

```json
{
  "eslint.validate": [
    "svelte",
    "typescript"
    "javascript",
  ],
  "svelte.enable-ts-plugin": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[svelte]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "svelte.svelte-vscode"
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "css.validate": false,
  "scss.validate": false
}
```

*I'm aware of `eslint.probe` as the "new" way to do it, but it actually doesn't work for me*.